# How to generate README.md from README.Rmd for R package?

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

Inspecting [dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) shows there's both a `README.md` file and a `README.Rmd` file.

In the `.md` file, it says

> README.md is generated from README.Rmd. Please edit that file

It's easy enough to create the `.Rmd` file, but how then is the `.md` file generated? Is it using roxygen2 or is there some terminal command (or something else)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply set `output: github_document` in the yaml at the top of the `.Rmd` and click knit.

Here's a small but complete RMarkdown document as an example:

````
---
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document that generates a github readme.md file.

```{r}
summary(iris)
```
````

Then simply click 'knit' like so:

[image]

Note:

- for markdown document that is *strictly* 'markdown' (as opposed to [github flavored markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/)), use `output: md_document` instead (but if it's for a github readme, you'll most likely want the github flavored version)

Comment: Just for a non-RStudio alternative, use `devtools::build_readme()`. But, as the answer above mentions, you _need_ to include `output: github_document` or the output with be html.